# Is chmod 777 safe for Shiny app hosted on AWS EC2?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny

I've hosted a web application (using `Shiny`, a R package for interactive web applications) on AWS EC2. I've also set up an authentication mechanism on the app with `shinymanger`(https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/). This authentication requires reading and writing from a sqlite database (`database.sqlite`) that stores user information (username, password, etc). In order to create new users in the authentication system, I need "write" permission, so I changed the permissions of the sqlite database with `chmod 777`

[Screenshot of user permission of sqlite database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inXjS.png)

**Question**: The AWS server is only owned by one other person, but I'm worried that since the web application is hosted on a public IP address, bad people could infiltrate the sensitive data. Is this permission setting safe? If not, how do I change the permission setting so that I can still read, write, and do everything that 777 allows, but safer!

Comment: As long as only shiny port is open on your instance security group, you're pretty much safe. Just restrict all other ports for your IP only.

Comment: You can have write permission with `chmod 755`. This will give `group` and `all` read and execute but **not write** permissions. Do you want `group` and `all` to be able to write sensitive data?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm not sure what `group` and `all` are referring to here. I just want the admin of the AWS EC2 server to be able to write sensitive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that everything is run by ubuntu.
If you're worried about security, you will probably want to run something like:
600 (rw-------) <- rule of least permissions. As long as the file is owned by the same user that the sqlite application runs as, this will work.

660 (rw-rw----) <- safe, group extended permissions. Allows members of the file group to r/w. Probably not needed, but can be used if multiple things will need r/w.

700 (rwx------) <- flexible user. Allows all actions from the user owning the file. Probably more permissions than needed, but I'm not super deep into SQLite (from my understanding it should only need r/w?)

770 (rwxrwx---) <- flexible group. Same as extended group permission, just also allows execute. Probably more permissions than are needed.

The one thing I would not recommend, specifically for a DB with file security concerns is any world permissions. The third perm should remain 0 to keep the file locked down to at least user/groups.

If you're curious about the full 'best practice'- I would recommend making an application specific user, changing the owner of the directory and file to that application user, and then applying all permissions as x00 permission sets (700 for directories, 600 or 640 for files).